# How do I properly exit my program?

Tags: c, winapi

Working with C and Win32, I have a problem where my program freezes instead of closing when a quit message is posted(Alt-F4 for example), and I have to end the process with task manager.

I have this in my main loop:(problem solved)

```
MSG msg;
while(1)
{
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            terminate = 1;
            while(terminate != 3) //each thread increments "terminate" by 1 before returning
            {
                Sleep(1);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    Sleep(1);
}
```

It will print "OK!" in the console and then freeze.

I think this could be because I have multiple threads and they are not terminated properly (but I read that if I return from my main() function the other threads should be killed automatically). If it helps one of those threads is an OpenGL rendering thread.

Comment: Apart from the other points posted by others, why a PeekMessage() loop?  What's wrong with GetMessage()?  Ths is not the first time I've seen this - why do developers keep wasting cores on CPU loops?  Apart from the waste, a CPU loop will impact the running of lower-priority threads, severely so on systems where the number of loops is the same or greater than the number of cores - another reason why threads might not terminate, (though probably not relevant to your problem with exit()).

Comment: I use a PeekMessage loop because that's what is used in the Code::Blocks OpenGL project. Can you please clarify the difference between PeekMessage and GetMessage? The msdn docs are not very clear: 

"Unlike GetMessage, the PeekMessage function does not wait for a message to be posted before returning."

Also all the main thread does is check for windows messages(I edited the code in the question, are you saying this is wrong?)

Comment: The difference is basically as stated - GetMesssage() blocks, waiting for a message.  While GetMessage is waiting, therefore, no CPU is used.  PeekMessage() does not block, so while waiting, your loop burns up a complete CPU core doing nothing.  The most efficient way of implementing what you seem to need is to get rid of the PM and sleep() loops and let your terminating threads post a WM_APP message that you can trap and do your 'countdown from 3'.  if 'Code::Blocks OpenGL'suggest PeekMessage and sleep loops, they are err.. 'not very good'

Comment: Ok now I understand(the Code::Blocks project does not only check for messages in that thread - it also does rendering) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` function is only just a thread, you are terminating just that one. However, for a process to end, all threads need to be properly terminated or it will run forever. You'll need to keep a reference the threads and terminate them once you receive the `WM_QUIT` message.

Comment: Actually the behavior of `exit` and `return` inside the `main` is compiler and even *compiler version* dependent in C, since C has no notion of threads. I am quite sure that in VC++ they changed this behavior recently.

Comment: I got it to work by making sure all other threads were ended (I thought exit(0); would take care of terminating all threads)

Comment: @Jonathan - aparrently not,  In most C environments,  abort(), or returning from main(), will call ExitProcess() and the OS will then indeed terminate all threads.  Calling exit() just exits the calling thread.

Comment: @MartinJames, exit() will exit from process， at least this is true on windows. exit() will eventually call __crtExitProcess(), and which then call ExitProcess() on windows. You can see the call stack if you debug exit and put a breakpoint on ExitProcess

Answer (score 0):

Exit is to exit from the entire process. Your process will clean up  when you call exit, e.g. Call the function registered with atexit, or call destructor of global object in case of c++. What about abort(), or terminateProcess.